# Using distinct and/or group by to filter select

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have also a question regarding distinct and/or group by. My table as follow:

```
|   art   |   ean             |   obs   |   vke   |
---------------------------------------------------
|  type    |  1234567890123   |    1    |   100   |
|  type    |  1234567890123   |    0    |   50    |
|  type    |  1234567890123   |    0    |   60    |
|  type    |  1234567890123   |    0    |   70    |
```

I need the query to select always the row with obs = 1 and only the cheapest of the others with obs = 0. All other equal EAN should not be listed at all. Is this possible ?

So the result should be:

```
|  type    |  1234567890123   |    1    |   100   |
|  type    |  1234567890123   |    0    |   50    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select art, ean, obs, vke 
from table_name
where obs = 1
union all
select art, ean, obs, min(vke) as vke
from table_name
where obs = 0
group by art, ean, obs
```

I'd `union` two results first one are all rows with `obs` aquals `1` and the second all rows grouped by `art`, `ean`, `obs` with `obs` equals `0` and `min` value of `vke`.

Read more about [`union`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) and [`group by`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT art, ean, obs, vke
FROM table_name
WHERE obs = 1
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT art, ean, obs, vke
    FROM table_name
    WHERE obs = 0
    ORDER BY vke
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: Hello - again similar problem: